# Запросы sql (База данных)

Tags: sql

Есть таблица ZAK_FL, нужно обновить все записи в таблице, плюс у которых фамилия оканчивается на ИН, поменять у них Кем выдан паспорт на TEST123

```
Create table ZAK_FL (
ID_ZAK_FL NUMBER primary key,
SURNAME VARCHAR (40) not null,
NAME_ VARCHAR (40) not null,
PATRONYMIC VARCHAR (40) not null,
PHONE_NAMBER VARCHAR (12) not null unique,
LIVING_ADDRESS VARCHAR (300) not null,
PASSPORT_SERIES NUMBER not null,
PASSPORT_NUMBER NUMBER not null,
PASSPORT_DATE_ DATE not null,
PASSPORT_DEPARTMENT_CODE NUMBER not null,
PASSPORT_ISSUED_BY_ VARCHAR2 (300) not null,
CONSTRAINT ZAK_FL UNIQUE (PASSPORT_SERIES, PASSPORT_NUMBER)
);
```

Comment: Ну что ж. Раз нужно - приступайте. Будут вопросы - обращайтесь.

Comment: Не получается))

Comment: @mrcrIstal Что не получается? Поищите описание SQL команды на обновление данных в таблице. Почитайте, как задать критерии выборки.

Answer (score 1):

Советы:

1. Составляем вопрос правильно, для отображения sql используйте блоки кода и соответствующее форматирование

```
    Create table ZAK_FL (
      ID_ZAK_FL                NUMBER primary key,
      SURNAME                  VARCHAR(40)   not null, #Фамилия
      NAME_                    VARCHAR(40)   not null,
      PATRONYMIC               VARCHAR(40)   not null,
      PHONE_NAMBER             VARCHAR(12)   not null unique,
      LIVING_ADDRESS           VARCHAR(300)  not null,
      PASSPORT_SERIES          NUMBER        not null,
      PASSPORT_NUMBER          NUMBER        not null,
      PASSPORT_DATE_           DATE          not null,
      PASSPORT_DEPARTMENT_CODE NUMBER        not null,
      PASSPORT_ISSUED_BY_      VARCHAR2(300) not null, #Выдан кем
      CONSTRAINT ZAK_FL UNIQUE (PASSPORT_SERIES, PASSPORT_NUMBER)
    );
```

2. Желательно указывать в какой БД планируется делать операции, и версию по возможности.
3. Явно указывать с какими столбцами должна идти операция.

   - Фамилия оканчивается на ИН это поле 'surname'
   - Кем выдан паспорт это поле 'PASSPORT_ISSUED_BY_'

Это увеличит шансы на быстрое получение ответа.

```
#Версия с учетом регистра
update ZAK_FL set PASSPORT_ISSUED_BY_='TEST123' where SURNAME like '%ИН'

#Версия без учета регистра
update ZAK_FL set PASSPORT_ISSUED_BY_='TEST123' where upper(SURNAME) like '%ИН'
```